# Javascript atom Feed parse with XPATH

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to parse an atom feed using javascript xpath API:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <category scheme="http://app.link.com/schemes" type="types"/>
   <link rel="app" href="http://app.link.com"/>
  <entry>
   <link rel="appnn" href="http://app.link.internal"/>
  </entry>  
</feed>
```

I tried to get the link(s) attributes using the javascript xPath API. This is what I have tried:

```
 var urlvar = '/feed/link/@href';
 var feed = xDoc.evaluate(urlvar, xDoc, null,XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
```

But the result is null for

> feed.stringValue
>   What I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

I tried

```
function feedNSResolver(prefix) {
  return "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
 }
```

without any luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with default namespace using xPath in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761517/parsing-xml-with-default-namespace-using-xpath-in-javascript)

Comment: updated about namespace resolver.

Comment: You might need to use a prefix in your XPath query. Any prefix should do, since your function will resolve all prefixes to the same namespace. Also: don't forget to pass your resolver function to the `evaluate` call!