# Test XPath expressions with namespaces in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, namespaces, google-chrome-devtools

I have a XML document opened in Chrome and I would like to test some XPath expressions. The XML document involves different namespaces. How do I define the prefix URIs?

For testing XPath expressions in Chrome I have used `$x("...")` so far.

Comment: What Chrome extension are you using to enter the XPath expressions?

Comment: @WimOmbelets None, `$x(string)` is built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as taken from developer.mozilla's [Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)

*Implementing a User Defined Namespace Resolver*

```
function nsResolver(prefix) {
  var ns = {
    'xhtml' : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    'mathml': 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'
  };
  return ns[prefix] || null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you searched for an element "description" anywhere inside the XML document, you could use the local-name() function. Example:

```
$x("//*[local-name()='description']")
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931817/xpath-expression-from-xml-with-namespace-prefix) on SO.