# HtmlAgilityPack getting <Item> tags

Tags: c#, parsing, tags, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use HTMLAgilityPack in order to parse an html page and get atom:links in which are contained in item tags . Here's a sample of the html :

```
<item><atom:link href="http://www.nytimes.com/2013/12/09/world/asia/justice-for-abused-
    afghan-women-still-elusive-un-report-says.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss" 
    rel="standout" />
```

I've  trying to get only the `atom:link` in `item` tags by doing the following :

```
        List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb nytRssPage = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument nytRssDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        nytRssDoc = nytRssPage.Load(rssUrl);

        var items = nytRssDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("item").ToList();// list of <item> tags
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var atomLink = item.SelectSingleNode("atom:link");
            string articleUrl = atomLink.InnerText;
            urlList.Add(articleUrl);
        }
```

The `urlList` is empty and I guess I've done something wrong.
It would be great if anyone could point me to the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Atom is a valid XML structure. Why would you use the HtmlAgilityPack to parse it? as for grabbing the atomLlink tag, you'll probably need to use either `/link` (without the namespace `atom`) or using the `local-name` function http://stackoverflow.com/a/8181480/736079

Comment: @jessehouwing , thanks for the answer . If so , i'd like to parse only the links which are contained in <item> tags. I still think the syntax i'm using is wrong

Comment: @jessehouwing, i've now tried Descendants("link") , it did not work and I've then tried SelectNodes("//link") instead - but it did not work as well.  If you've got any suggestions I'd be grateful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse an xml, you don't need HtmlAgilityPack

```
var url = "http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/International.xml";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(url);

XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

var items = xDoc.Descendants("item")
            .Select(item => new
            {
                Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
                Url = item.Element(atom + "link") != null 
                          ? (string)item.Element(atom + "link").Attribute("href") 
                          : (string)item.Element("link")
            })
            .ToList();
```

---

Alternatively, you can use  [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class too

```
var url = "http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/International.xml";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(url);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xDoc.CreateReader());
```

Now you can loop `feed.Items` .

Answer (score 2):

The following code extracts all links:

```
 var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//item/*[name()='atom:link']/@href");
```

If you want to grab them from each item node, you'll need to use:

```
 var link = item.SelectSingleNode(@"./*[name()='atom:link']/@href");
```

And I still suggest you load the Atom feed in a proper XML structure (using Linq to XML or an XPathNavigable) or using a dedicated Atom library like [Atom.NET](http://atomnet.sourceforge.net/) or the [Windows feeds API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs).

Comment: thanks for the answer ! what is "item" in  var link = item.SelectSingleNode(@"./*[name()='atom:link']/@href"); ?

Comment: item would have been the item from `foreach (var item in items)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(
    "<item><atom:link href=\"http://www.nytimes.com/2013/12/09/world/asia/justice-for-abused-afghan-women-still-elusive-un-report-says.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss\" rel=\"standout\" />");

var urls = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//item/*[name()='atom:link']")
    .SelectMany(node => node.Attributes.AttributesWithName("href").Select(attr => attr.Value))
    .ToList();
```