# Get xml value based on another value in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, gml

I have some gml that looks like this:

```
<gml:featureMember>
    <a:location>ABCD</a:location>
    <a:ElevatedPoint>
        <gml:pos>44.0 1.2</gml:pos>
        <a:elevation uom="FT">23</a:elevation>
    </a:ElevatedPoint>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
    <a:location>EFJH</a:location>
    <a:ElevatedPoint>
        <gml:pos>33.3 -6.9</gml:pos>
        <a:elevation uom="FT">244</a:elevation>
    </a:ElevatedPoint>
</gml:featureMember>
```

I want to get the `gml:pos` based on value of `a:location`. So for example, I want the position related to location `ABCD`. I'm guessing using xpath is the way forward but not really sure where to start.

Any help appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information.

**UPDATE**

This is what I've go so far:

```
var positions = document.evaluate("/featureMember/location[ABCD]/ElevatedPoint/pos", xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Comment: Without namespace problem the Xpath should be `/featureMember/location[.="ABCD"]/following-sibling::ElevatedPoint/pos`

Comment: Or `/featureMember[location[.="ABCD"]]/ElevatedPoint/pos`

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on namespacing?

Comment: I can't to work with xml in js :(

Answer (score 0):

Never used Xpath on gml, but this is what i'd do:

```
/featureMember/location[desired_value]/ElevatedPoint/pos
```

keep in mind that this is XML xpath syntax and i have no idea how it has to look for GML, and that this will return ALL positions of nodes with the correct location.

Comment: I tried this but I think the namespacing is a problem. I've update above to show what I've got so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8181480/2102710 Try that, it's a workaround for namespacing...